# legend icon width changes in google line chart

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

I have used google chart from this location

`https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Example`

[image]

Is there any possibility to change the width and height of the legend icons i.e the blue and red rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the documentation:

```
legend: {position: 'top', textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 16}}

legend.textStyle: {color: <string>, fontName: <string>, fontSize: <number>}
```

Is it what you was looking for ?

Comment: I need to reduce the size of the square only not the font size. Is there any possiblity?